# How to check if user is signed in or not in firebase auth while registering for the app?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to change the colour of the status bar based on the theme and whether the user is signed in or not.

In my app, there are multiple pages for registration like Sign In, Confirm phone number, take user information etc.

In these pages, I want to check if the user has successfully registered then do something otherwise do something else. Here is the code snippet for the same.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((firebaseUser) {
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
    // signed out
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      isThemeLight
          ? SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
              statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
            )
          : SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
              statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
    );
  } else {
    // signed in
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
  }
});
```

But during the registration process `firebaseUser == null` is false, so I am getting into the else block.

What should happen is until the registration process is complete it should stay in the if block. I am unable to find a way to solve this issue.

Any help would be great. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you invoking any signIn method before calling the currentUser()?

Comment: @racr0x Yes, I am invoking the signIn method on the first screen and then checking the value of currentUser on the next one.

Comment: If your signIn is successful, you will have the firebaseUser. In order to your firebaseUser be null, you need to invoke signIn only at the end of the process. If you want to signIn first, you will need to handle the state with some other variable to know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is listen to `AuthStateChanged` here's how you do it:

```
    FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.listen((currentUser) async {
 if (currentUser == null) {
    // signed out
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      isThemeLight
          ? SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
              statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
            )
          : SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
              statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
    );
  } else {
    // signed in
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
  }
    });
```